# How to add a title and author to exsheets?

Tags: exsheets

I have a nice `exsheets` template, however i just cannot manage to add a title and author! (if i add one it  still compiles but title is never shown.). Please help me add a tilte & author?

Here is my template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu}

% due to a bug in versions >0.3a:
\providecommand*\checkedchoicebox{\ckeckedchoicebox}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{choices*}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[choices*]{itemjoin=\qquad}
\newcommand*\choice{\item[\choicebox]}
\newcommand*\correctchoice{\PrintSolutionsTF{\item[\checkedchoicebox]}{\item[\choicebox]}}

\begin{document}
\section{Exercises}
\begin{question}\label{qu:one}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
 You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:one}.
\end{solution}
\begin{question}\label{qu:two}
 This is the second question.

 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the second question.

 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}

 \noindent You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:two}.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with `article` document class? Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{A Small \LaTeX{} Exercise Template}
\author{Your Name  \\
    Your Company / University  \\
        }
        \date{}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\SetupExSheets{counter-format=se.qu}

% due to a bug in versions >0.3a:
\providecommand*\checkedchoicebox{\ckeckedchoicebox}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\newlist{choices}{itemize}{1}
\newlist{choices*}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[choices*]{itemjoin=\qquad}
\newcommand*\choice{\item[\choicebox]}
\newcommand*\correctchoice{\PrintSolutionsTF{\item[\checkedchoicebox]}{\item[\choicebox]}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Exercises}
\begin{question}\label{qu:one}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the first question.
 \begin{choices}
  \choice Wrong answer
  \correctchoice This is a correct answer
  \correctchoice This is another answer
  \choice Wrong answer
 \end{choices}
 You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:one}.
\end{solution}
\begin{question}\label{qu:two}
 This is the second question.

 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
 This is the second question.

 \begin{choices*}
  \correctchoice True
  \choice False
  \correctchoice True
  \choice false
 \end{choices*}

 \noindent You find the question on page~\pageref{qu:two}.
\end{solution}

\section{Solutions}
\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks! that solves my problem. (don't know why i didnt find it myself sorry)

Comment: @Machupicchu, Your welcome.